# Is there any way to control the scenario execution during run-time in Karate API / Cucumber?

Tags: web-services, automation, cucumber, karate

I have a feature file with several scenarios ( **ex:3** ) that are separated by **@Scenario** annotation.

Sometimes, I don't want to execute all the scenarios except few scenarios.

Is there any built-in method or keyword or solution available in Karate API / Cucumber framework?

**Sample Feature File:**

```
Feature: Webservices Testing
  I want to use this template for my feature file

Background:
   * def APIHelperClass = Java.type('com.org.utilities.APIHelperClass')
############################SOAP REQUEST##############################################
@Scenario1
Scenario: Get Employees Details
  * url 'http://101.154.121.135:1234//EmployeeSummary_PS?wsdl'
  Given request read ('employees.xml')
  When method post
  Then status 200

  * print 'Status Code :',responseStatus 

############################SOAP REQUEST##############################################

@Scenario2
Scenario: Get Products Details
 * url 'http://101.154.121.135:1234//ProductSummary_PS?wsdl'
 Given request read ('getProductsRequest.xml')
 When method post
 Then status 200
```

I'm not able to control the Scenario execution using following script.

**Option1:**

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(tags = {"@Scenario1", "@Scenario3"})
public class KarateClass {

}
```

**Option 2:**

```
@RunWith(Karate.class)
@CucumberOptions(tags = {"@Scenario1", "@Scenario3"})
public class KarateClass {

}
```

The above mentioned options not working which means, while executing the feature file using my own @Test method it executes **3** scenarios.

What wrong did I do in the class that I don't know?

Can you please give the solutions for that?

EDITED:

In my **@Test** method where in I have used the following script to execute the Feature File.

```
Map<String, Object> response =   CucumberRunner.runClasspathFeature("com/org/features/rci_api_testing.feature", args, true);
```

And **@CucumberOptions** used another class i.e. Karate Class

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(tags = {"@Scenario1", "@Scenario3"})
public class KarateClass {

}
```

Thanks,

Comment: Hi, I have accepted the answers...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use tags: https://github.com/intuit/karate#cucumber-tags

So you can from the command line:

`mvn test -Dcucumber.options="--tags @Scenario1"`

or if you are using a JUnit runner:

`@CucumberOptions(tags = {"@Scenario1", "@Scenario2"})`

Comment: So I have to change this @CucumberOptions(tags = {"@Scenario1", "@Scenario2"}) in the Karate class annotation instead of @RunWith(Karate.class). Am I correct?

Comment: Ok..I got it...Thank you

Comment: I tried with this @RunWith(Karate.class)
@CucumberOptions(tags = {"@Scenario1","@Scenario3"})
public class KarateClass {
} but it executes @Scenario2 too...

Comment: I have edited the main post..please let me know what else you need I will update in the post itself..

Comment: You must be doing something else wrong. I am not able to figure from what you have provided. Hope somebody else can help you. All the best :P